# Initializing a final variable-length array inline

Tags: java, arrays, static, initialization, inline

Suppose I wanted to initialize a `static final` array that is N copies of some object (for simplicity, let's say `String`).  We must initialize it inline because it's `static final`, and we can't use the array literal because it is variable-length (or infeasibly long):

```
static final int N = 10000;
static final String foo = "baz";
//create a static array of 10000 copies of "baz"
static final String[] STRINGS = make_array_of(foo, N);
```

Is there a way to do this inline in Java (that is, does some function perform `make_array_of`)?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27920829/438154) answer in the duplicate.

Comment: That's a perfect match!  Not sure why that answer was buried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a static initializer:

```
private static final String[] ARRAY;

static {
    // Initialize the array here
}
```

Note that the initializer must be *after* the variable declaration.

---

for your particular situation, the `Arrays` class can make things easy:

```
static {
    STRINGS = new String[N];
    Arrays.fill(STRINGS, foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can try using

```
Stream.generate(Supplier).limit(SIZE).toArray(Type[]::new);
```

(or performing much better in parallel, but little less readable)

```
IntStream.range(0,SIZE).mapToObject(i->value).toArray(Type[]::new);
```

like

```
private static final String[] ARRAY = Stream
        .generate(() -> foo) //you can also generate value dynamically here
        .limit(N)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```