# Java fill array with N elements of a given string character (?)

Tags: java, arrays, char, fill

I want to generate this string:

```
?, ?, ?, ?, ?
```

I can generate it in PHP like this:

```
$s = implode(", ", array_fill(0, 5, "?"));
```

I can generate it in Python like this:

```
s = ", ".join(["?"] * 5)
```

I can generate it in Swift like this:

```
let s = Array(repeating: "?", count: 5).joined(separator: ", ")
```

But... how can I do it with Java? My initial guess is about using something like this:

```
String s = String.format("%s", String.join(", ", ...));
```

... and in those three dots end my happiness for now. If I resort to something like `new StringBuilder(5)` then I have to do `.append("?")` 5 times and then `.toString()` gives me a string (I'm looking for an array or a list of some sort). If I try something like `Arrays.fill()` it must work on an existing array (and I would like to do it in a one-liner **if possible**).

The idea for this is to compose a list of question-mark parameters to construct SQL statements like `INSERT INTO %s (%) VALUES (%s);` and give the placeholders their appropriate content before making a prepared statement and feeding it with data. I used 5 question marks as an example but it can be any number of question marks (one mark for each table column I want to specify in the insertion).

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: @YCF_L That will result in `"?, ?, ?, ?, ?, "` instead of `"?, ?, ?, ?, ?"`

Comment: @user yes this is correct

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276470/create-an-array-with-n-copies-of-the-same-value-object

Comment: @Savior Indeed. Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `String.join(", ", Collections.nCopies(5, "?"))` should do the job. [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.Iterable)) puts it together with a delimeter, and [`Collections.nCopies`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,T)) makes an immutable `List` with the given element repeated n times (5 in this case).

Answer (score 3):

It's just as easy in Java:

```
IntStream.range(0,5).mapToObj(x -> "?").collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
```